# Is possible spawn terminal using NodeJS and trigger closeHandler if that terminal has been Closed (with press close button) and with CTRL+C

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, terminal, child-process

**Hello!**

My OS currently in Linux, my goal is to `.spawn()` another terminal, and watch the parent process output with that terminal using command `tail -f app.log`, it's run very well using this...

**Code**

```
const xec = spawn('gnome-terminal', ['-x', 'bash', '-c', '"tail -f app.log; exec bash"'], {
    shell: true
});
```

but I can't trigger that `.spawn()` if the terminal has been Closed and with CTRL+C, even using this...

**Code**

```
// Trigger when terminal is show
xec.stdout.on('end', () => {
    console.log('stdout: End');
});

// Not response
xec.stdout.on('exit', () => {
    console.log('stdout: Exit');
});

// Trigger when terminal is show
xec.stdout.on('close', () => {
    console.log('stdout: Close');
});

// Not response
xec.on('close', () => {
    console.log('xec: Close');
});

// Trigger when terminal is show
xec.on('exit', () => {
    console.log('xec: Exit');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can trigger the close button and also with CTRL+C too with this...

**Code**

```
const command = 'gnome-terminal --disable-factory -- /bin/bash -i -c "tail -f app.log; exec bash"'
const xec = exec(command, (err, out, derr) => {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
        console.log(`Out: ${out}`);
        console.log(`derr: ${derr}`);
});
```

I am just adding `--disable-factory`. Also `--disable-factory` didn't support with a newer version but so far I am using `v3.28.1` it's still works fine. See this [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729034/gnome-terminal-disable-factory-support-problem) also this [blog](https://chrisirwin.ca/posts/multiple-instances-of-gnome-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

If not clear from the OP question if the CTRL/C is sent to the original window, or to the spanwed window. On surface the problem described related to CTLR/C send to the original window (where the node program was started).

The 'CTRL/C' can be captured as signal event on the global process object. See https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events

```
const process = require('process');
...
process.on('SIGINT', () => { console.log("INT")));
```

Side Note: Consider add '--wait' to the gnome command line. It will allow node the get proper signals from the child process, and enable the xec.on events to work. Eliminating the need put events on the xec.stdout

```
const xec = spawn('gnome-terminal', ['--wait' '-e', 'tail -f app.log'], {
    shell: true
});
```

Comment: Sorry before that the title of my question is not clear, I will change it, and Thanks for the answer! But your code didn't trigger when I press the close button at the top right in the terminal, it's only triggered when I press CTRL+C in my child terminal (child process)